# Unit Testing Promises in AngularJS Error: Expected a spy, but got getCtrl({ })

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have service created which returns product details via httppost request
I have controller through which i call service `__getProductService.getproductDetailsPull().then(function(response){__`
and i get the data in controller

I  wrote a test case for this in jasmine-karma by injecting spy

```
__spyOn(getProduct, 'getproductDetailsPull').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);__
```

**But i got errors for promises **

#### Error 1

```
Expected a spy, but got deleteCtrl({ }).
```

#### Error 2

```
.then is not a function
```

**Service Code**

```
   var myapp = angular.module('abcservice');
    myapp.service('getProductService',function($http,$q){

        var productDetails = [];
        var productResponse = null;

        this.setproduct= function() {
            var obj = {
                    adminId : 15,
                    productOrderID: 174824929577
            };
                if (this.productResponse == null) {
                    this.productResponse = $http.post('someurl',obj).success(function(data, status, headers,config) {
                        this.productResponse = mapJson(data);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers,config)
                        {
                        console.log("error while fetching data from spring controller:" +error);
                    });
                }
            return this.productResponse; 
        };

        this.getproductDetailsPull = function(productResponse) {
            return this.productResponse;
        };
    }
```

**Controller Code**

```
angular
    .module('getCtrl', []);
getCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'getProductService'];
    function getCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope, getProductService) {

            getProductService.getproductDetailsPull().then(function(response){


            $scope.displayData = response.data.productorder;
            $scope.lineItemData = response.data.OrderItem;

    }
}
```

**Jasmine Test Case**

```
 describe('getCtrl Test', function() {

        var $scope = null;
        var $getProduct = null;
        var $rootScope = null;
        var deferred,$q;

        beforeEach(module('abcservice','getCtrl'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_,$rootScope,getProduct,_$q_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $q = _$q_;;
        deferred = _$q_.defer();

        spyOn(getProduct, 'getproductDetailsPull').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        controller = $controller('getCtrl', { $scope: $scope,$rootScope: $rootScope,getProduct:getProduct });
        }));

        it('Exists controller, function() { 

            expect(controller).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, getProduct is not the name of your service.  You need to inject the service like:

```
 beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_,$rootScope,getProductService
```

The spy should be int he format spyOn(object, "methodName"), so in your case:

```
spyOn(getProductService, 'getproductDetailsPull')
```

Consider doing this for your promise:

```
spyOn(getProductService, 'getproductDetailsPull').and.returnValue($q.when())
```

Your test case is a little weird I assume your just doing that to get things working but you probably want something like:

```
it('Product is fetched, function() { 
        scope.$digest(); // if your using $q you need this (maybe move it to before call)
        expect(getProductService.getproductDetailsPull).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```